# React input mask issue with onChange event focus on cursor position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masking, input-mask

I am trying to implement Input Mask with children as input component, I used https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask. The problem is while onChange() event triggers setState() is called and the state is updated. While updating the state the component is re-rendered. So the state value is also updated and cursor moved to the end of the input value.I am expecting it should stayed on changing position. Here is my code

```
import InputMask from 'react-input-mask';

const [state, setState] = useState<StateTypes>({
    myVal: '123.123.123-56'
});

const onChangeValue = (inputVal: any) => {
    setState({
      myVal: inputVal
});
};

<InputMask mask="999.999.999-99" onChange={onChangeValue} value={state.myVal}>
 <Input name={'myVal'} />
</InputMask>
```

After setting the state input component is re-rendered, so cursor point moved to the end. Can someone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Found any solution to this? I encountered this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
            window.document.getElementById("expiryDtId").focus();
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
```

got solution by using id and javascript

```
  <InputMask
        mask="99/99/9999" 

        id={"expiryDtId"}
/>
```